# Running the Mathematica script in SQL Server

Tags: scripting, sql

Hi i am trying to learn mathematica.

I am following instruction in one of the questions asked before and did the following:

In SQL Server a stored procedure is created as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.math_execute_external_script
    @scriptName [varchar](1000)
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @command varchar(1000)  
    set @command='"C:\Users\atfai\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\rproject1\rproject1\' + @scriptName + '"'
    Exec Master..xp_Cmdshell @command
END
```

I am executing the file as follows

```
EXECUTE dbo.math_execute_external_script 'mathematicaScript.bat'
```

The batch file contain the following

```
@echo off
setlocal
PATH = C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.4;%PATH%
start MathKernel -script "C:\Users\atfai\WolframWorkspaces\Base\MathematicaProject1\MathematicaProject1.m"
endlocal
```

`MathematicaProject1.m` contains `1+1`

now when i execute i get `NULL` in sql server

Can someone explain how to get the answer `2` in sql server?

Comment: somebody people see what i am doing wrong here. Please help!!!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was abandoned by the OP. Without feedback, it is difficult to make progress on a question that is dependent on the user's setup.

Comment: I switched jobs and relocated and am now back to using SQL Server and Mathematica together. Will reapproach this question again.

Answer (score 0):

first of all make sure to [enable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/xp-cmdshell-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver16) xp_cmdshell.
Next is that your SQL Server Service Account needs to have access permission to the file you are trying to run. As this is located in C:\Users probably this is not the case.
I would recommend creating a seperate directory on your data drive and giving the SQL Server service Account read and write access to it.

Last of all: What are you trying to accomplish here? Generally speaking activating xp_cmdshell can be considered a security risk. You are opening up executing all sorts of command line calls from SQL...just think that a hacker could format your disk drives over SQL injection. I admit that this discussion is controversial and there are also [voices](https://sqlundercover.com/2023/04/12/ive-got-99-problems-but-xp_cmdshell-aint-one/) that say it boils down to security settings. I personally would prefer to write a powershell or cmd script executing mathematica and writing the result into a SQL table. This script can be scheduled in SQL Server Agent. Alternatively you can run your mathematica script from the agent in a [commandline task.](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2014/replace-xpcmdshell-command-line-use-with-sql-server-agent/)

Best regards

Martin